# Show div dynamically if related checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a filter with jQuery and checkboxes. For example when the user clicks on the `2013` checkbox it just displays the `div` with the same `class` and keeps others hidden.

However it's not working. Does anyone know how to make it work? Thank you

```js
$('.result').hide();

$(".filters :checkbox").click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.result .' + id + '').slideToggle('slow');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <input type="checkbox" id="2013" name="2013"><label for="2013">2013</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2014" name="2014"><label for="2014">2014</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2014" name="2015"><label for="2015">2015</label>
</div>
<div class="results">
  <div class="result 2013">my text</div>
  <div class="result 2014">my text</div>
  <div class="result 2015">my text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here:

- You should hide the `.result` elements using CSS to avoid the [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)
- Add the `value` attribute to the checkboxes to keep the HTML valid. You can use this instead of the `id` in your JS logic. Also, give them all the same `name`. Although you may not necessarily use it here, it's still better practice and more semantic.
- Use the `change` event, not `click`, when dealing with checkboxes and radio inputs. This is so your code still works for people who navigate using the keyboard.
- There's no need for `== true` when evaluating booleans.
- There's no need to concatenate `''` at the end of a string.

However the main issues are that you have a gap in the selector string you build; `$('.result .' + id)` should be `$('.result.' + id)`. In addition you need to hide the deselected checkboxes again, which can be done by using `filter()` and `slideUp`.

With all that said, try this:

```js
let $results = $('.result');
let $filters = $(".filters :checkbox").change(function() {
  $results.slideUp('slow');
  $filters.filter(':checked').each(function() {
    $results.filter('.' + this.value).stop().slideDown('slow');
  })
});
```

```css
.result {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2013">
    2013
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2014">
    2014
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2015">
    2015
  </label>
</div>
<div class="results">
  <div class="result 2013">Result 2013</div>
  <div class="result 2014">Result 2014</div>
  <div class="result 2015">Result 2015</div>
</div>
```

Finally, note that I placed the checkboxes within the `label` elements. This increases the hit area you can click on to check the box, and it also removes the need for the `for` attribute.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped.